# Is "The Matter of the Seggri" a novelette or a novella?

Tags: novella, ursula-k-le-guin

I listened to Le Guin's story "*The Matter of the Seggri*" in the anthology *The Found and the Lost*, which purports to be a collection of [all Le Guin's novellas](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/29868611-the-found-and-the-lost).

However, on Wikipedia and [ISFDB award history](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?40605), it seems to be pegged as a novelette.

I know currently, Hugo award categories classify a novelette as being 7,500-17,500 words, and a novella as 17,500-40,000. I'm writing a piece about some notable novellas, and the novella as a form -- and I don't know if I can refer to this one (or, indeed, any of the other possibly-novellas in *The Found and the Lost*).

What is the approximate wordcount for "The Matter of Seggri"? By wordcount, is it a novella, or at least close?

Comment: Seems like a Writing stack exchange type question.

Comment: Maybe literature.stackexchange.com instead.

Comment: @MishaR: This would be off-topic on Writing.SE as it is about an existing work.

Comment: The story's SF, but the word count isn't -- and if you have the story available to read and write about, why not do an approximate word count on your own?

Comment: @ZeissIkon If the story's SF, then why is this closed? Questions about on-topic works are generally on-topic.

Comment: Asking how long a story is has nothing to do with its subject matter.  Perhaps we should all have just downvoted (for lack of research effort?), but even though the work asked about is SF, I don't consider a mechanical question like this to be on topic.  I could be wrong, of course, I didnt' read the FAQ instants before voting.  Of course, there were the other four votes, one of which was seeming cast seconds before mine...

Comment: @ZeissIkon We accept lots of questions which aren't specifically about subject matter - see e.g. [How should we handle questions that are about non-SF/F elements in a SF/F work?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6594/31394) or the [tag:behind-the-scenes] tag or all our questions about ratings, music, etc. etc.

Comment: @Randal'Thor Nothing stopping you from casting a reopen vote, I guess.

Comment: @ZeissIkon Well, except that I'm a mod and such a vote would be instantly binding. I'm trying to understand why it was closed before hammering it back open singlehandedly.

Comment: "The story is set on Seggri, a planet featuring extreme gender segregation. Seggri is also a part of the fictional interplanetary society called the Ekumen; the story belongs to the Hainish Cycle."  So the content of the story is definitely on-topic.  And we accept _all kinds_ of questions about movies and actors in them that is not related to the SF content of the movies themselves.  What other TNG actors might reappear in the new Picard show, for instance.

Comment: @Randal'Thor The question isn't about the story, though. The question is about the number of words that would qualify a novella. The story is an example, but any story of that length could be an equally valid example - and the answer to the question would be the same.

Comment: The story is an SF story, and the novelette/novella distinction is pretty fundamental in SF awards culture (which is why the Hugos, the Nebulas, and other major prizes _make_ the distinction in their categories :-) ). I have the story only as audio, and can't make the estimate myself. All that being said, I could certainly understand wordcount for a particular story being too trivial a question for the site.

Comment: @MishaR No, the question *explicitly says* how many words qualify a novella (17,500-40,000), according to the criteria the OP is interested in, and asks about whether *this specific story* qualifies or not.

Comment: @Randal'Thor - That's fair enough, I suppose....

Comment: Purely for the record, The Found and the Lost contains 13 stories. [ISFDB](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?40605) classifies 5 as 'novelettes' and the remainder as 'novellas'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The story contains **16,566 words.**

---

This puts it into the *novelette* category, albeit at the top end.

> Best Novelette: Awarded for a science fiction or fantasy story of between seven thousand five hundred (7,500) and seventeen thousand five hundred (17,500) words.
>
> <sub><sup>[Hugo Award Categories - The Official Rules](http://www.thehugoawards.org/hugo-categories/)</sup></sub>

Comment: Since the book was marketed as containing selected *novellas*, you'd have a fair shot at getting your money back from Amazon ("not as described") but you wouldn't win in a court of law.

Comment: Thank you! Just to confirm, is this a simple wordcount from a file?

Comment: @Standback - Yes. I acquired an electronic copy and put it in MS word, then ran the word count tool. Given the number of 'word-soup' fake alien words, these figures might be a little bit off, but only plus or minus a few tens.

Answer (score 3):

Approximately?  Somewhere around 12k, which is enough less than 17.5k that an error of 25% still won't make it a novella.

I'm basing the estimate on its appearance in the collection [*The Birthday of the World*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?130261) where it occupies 46 pages.  (I selected that particular entry from the [list of all publications](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?40605) because a paperback has the most consistent size, as opposed to trade paper which can vary quite a lot.)  A paperback has (as a standard industry estimate) 250 words per page *on average*.  Multiplying 46 * 250 gives 11 500 which rounds up to 12k.

Note that even if the pages are very dense, with minimal margins, I don't think the word count could possibly exceed 380 words/page, which is what would be required to reach a novella length (17 500 / 46 = 380.4).

In short, without having the actual text it's not possible to give an exact word-count, but based on the page count it *is* possible to answer the question that the story is of novelette length, not novella.  (Using the Hugo definitions, that is.)